# Unable to create foreign key on mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi i'm trying to create a simple MySQL database. I write the following script

```
CREATE TABLE office (
   num_office varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   name varchar(45),
   address varchar(45),
   numder varchar(4),
   city varchar(45)
 );



CREATE TABLE office_phone(
n_office varchar(10) NOT NULL,
phone varchar(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(n_office,phone),
FOREIGN KEY (n_office) REFERENCES office(num_office)
ON DELETE RESTRICT 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

but Error Code 1822 is appeared. 
How can i fix it? 
thank you in andvance

Comment: The full error message says everything : `Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constaint. Missing index for constraint.`

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys can reference only columns that are primary keys or at least have an index on them (thanks @Uueerdo). For example:

```
ALTER TABLE OFFICE ADD CONSTRAINT offnum_unq UNIQUE (NUM_OFFICE);
```

This forces the referenced column to have unique values and also creates an index on it. Or you could also do:

```
CREATE INDEX offnum_idx ON OFFICE(NUM_OFFICE);
```

Now your second `CREATE` should work.

Comment: Slight correction: In MySQL, referenced columns (or column combinations) only need to be indexed; it is not required that the index enforce uniqueness.

Comment: @Uueerdo You're right. I fixed my answer. I've always used FKs with PKs or UNQ columns so didn't notice this before. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the cases where you actually would want to reference a non-unique indexes are fairly rare.

Answer (score 1):

Reference column (Column you referenced as foreign key) should have the index added to it. You can add Index to the column "num_office" in "office" table and try creating the "office_phone" table. Refer the following queries

Create Table "office" with the index added to "num_office"

```
CREATE TABLE office (
  num_office varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(45),
  address varchar(45),
  numder varchar(4),
  city varchar(45),
  INDEX num_office_idx (num_office)
```

);

OR you can add index after creating the "office" table using

```
ALTER TABLE office Add Index num_office_indx (num_office);
```

This will let you to create the table "office_phone" successfully with the reference key pointing to "num_office" column of "office" table.

```
CREATE TABLE office_phone(
 n_office varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 phone varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(n_office,phone),
 FOREIGN KEY (n_office) REFERENCES office(num_office)
 ON DELETE RESTRICT 
 ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Refer [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) page for more details